# ¿Duda como funcionaria el menu de una pag web dinamica?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Pues no he encontrado una forma de hacerlo optima por internet y no quisiera inventar algo **ineficiente** o mal **estructurado**.

Una vez dicho eso me explico:

En el caso de tener una pagina web con una barra de menu arriba con diferentes apartados como podria ser : 'Inicio','Amigos', 'Acerca de ..', etc..
Si la estoy haciendo con trozos de php... tendria que tener un **html** por cada categoria ?

No podria usar un solo html e ir llamando diferentes fragmentos html o no se como seria la forma mas optima, porque si no tendria que hacer un html por cada menu y submenu y estoy seguro de que hay maneras mas faciles.

Solo necesito saber la **tecnica correcta.**

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask] y del mismo modo hacer el [tour] ya que al momento tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, por que cada usuario según su experiencia y preferencia te puede recomendar cosas distintas saludos

Comment: gracias y disculpa, sabes de algun sitio donde pueda aprender eso ?

Answer (score 1):

Si trabajas con php, una manera de incluir elementos comunes en varias páginas (como menús, cabeceras, pies de página) es incluirlas en un fichero php y luego desde cada una de tus páginas haces un `require`

Esta es la estructura que podrían tener las páginas (algo similar):

```
<?php

require('./header.php');
require('./menu.php');

// Cosas...

require('./footer.php');

?>
```

Por contra, si sólo trabajas con html, una manera de no tener que repetir ciertos fragmentos es escribirlos mediante javascript. Puedes cargar un js que tenga una función que sea la que escribe el menú. Bien sea mediante `document.write` o manipulando el DOM, por ejemplo con `createElement`